# Incorrect credentials response in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 6
```

I created the credentials file, as follows:

```
EDITOR=vi rails credentials:edit

production:
  mysql:
    db: acme-production
    user: deploy
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  smartagent:
    token: lnroftb7sgr8c7f1ogqvij24xl

test:
  mysql:
    db: acme-test
    user: deploy
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  smartagent:
    token: lnroftb7sgr8c7f1ogqvij24xl

secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

master.key is in the correct place (in the config folder, locally, and as an environment setting on the server).

I am having trouble with the smartagent token.

When I do:

```
rails c
```

and

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :mysql, :db)
```

I get:

```
=> "acme-test"
```

However, when I do:

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :smartagent, :token)
```

I get:

```
=> nil
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

## Solution:

I deleted the credentials file, re-populated it, and restarted the Rails app. That fixed the problem, so this must have been either an indentation issue (spaces vs tabs), or that the server had not restarted properly, after earlier changes were made

Comment: It could be an indentation issue. Make sure that your credentials file is indented with spaces thoroughly

Comment: The indentations are in what I posted

Comment: Make sure that Rails.env.to_sym is :test and not :development. I copy pasted your credentials on one of mine and doing `Rails.application.credentials.dig(:test, :smartagent, :token)` works normally on Rails 6, ruby 2.5.7

Comment: @cesartalves I am using Rails.env.to_sym, please re-read my question, the first query works fine

Comment: try doing `spring stop` and stop your server; check for `ps aux | grep rails` to see if it's running. Maybe it's an in memory caching issue and the credentials are not updated ?

Comment: I understood that. But can you double check that Rails.env.to_sym is :test?